# Unexpected behavior running multiple detached threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to create a multi-threaded program that does some calculations.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
mutex mtx;
class fire {
    public:
    int th;
    fire(int thr) {
        this->th = thr;
    }
    void execute() {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            mtx.lock();
            cout << "thread : " << this->th << " loop : " << x << endl;
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    }
    thread exec() {
        cout << "Execute\n";
        return thread([=] { execute(); } );
    }
};

int main(void) {
    list<fire> move;
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        move.push_back(fire(x));
    }
    for ( auto x : move) {
        thread z = x.exec();
        z.detach();
    }
    cout << "End\n";
}
```

The output is :

```
Execute
Execute
Execute
thread : 2 loop : 0
thread : 2 loop : 1
thread : 2 loop : 2
thread : 2 loop : 3
thread : 2 loop : 4
thread : 2 loop : 5
thread : 2 loop : 6
thread : 2 loop : 7
thread : 2 loop : 8
thread : 2 loop : 9
Execute
thread : 3 loop : 0
thread : 3 loop : 1
thread : Execute
4 loop : 2
thread : 4 loop : 3
Execute
thread : 5 loop : 0
thread : 5 loop : 1
Execute
Execute
End
```

As you can see this is not the expected behaviour and I am exhausted with Google searches.
Why am I not seeing normal behavior from this simple piece of code?

Comment: If you detach the threads then the threads will not be guaranteed run to completion; they will be terminated at the moment when main() returns and the process is destroyed.  To avoid that, you should not detach them; rather add an extra for-loop at the end of main() that calls join() on each thread.

Comment: Do you want the program to keep running until all threads finish? If so, your need to call `pthread_exit` in `main`. Returning from `main` terminates the process.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `pthread_exit` at the end of `main`. Returning from `main` terminates the process, not giving the detached threads time to run.

But as a general rule, it would probably be better not to detach the threads.

Comment: Calling pthread_exit() did not help.  Instead of the programs normal behaviour I get a series of loops through the last thread.  By series I mean thread 7 : loop 0-9 over and over again.

Comment: Ahh, you have another bug. You create `move` on the first thread's stack but the other threads access its members. So you can't allow that stack to be destroyed until all the threads are finished.

Comment: Hmm, I can’t find `pthread_exit` in the C++ standard. That might work on Unix systems, but even then, there is no requirement in C++ that calling `pthread_exit` from `main` will do anything sensible. In particular, I’ll bet it won’t destroy global objects.